Job bookmark not working when joining 2 tables in AWS Glue
our current script was generated using visual ETL on AWS Glue. It works but the incremental loading (with job bookmark) does not work. for every run all the data is uploaded in s3 again. What would be the possible issues here?
things I already did

enabled Job bookmark
added the job bookmark keys on different places
multiple columns for bookmark keys to ensure uniqueness of each row
used the visual ETL and then added some lines manually
job.commit() and job.init() is in the code

    import sys
    from awsglue.transforms import *
    from awsglue.utils import getResolvedOptions
    from pyspark.context import SparkContext
    from awsglue.context import GlueContext
    from awsglue.job import Job
    from awsgluedq.transforms import EvaluateDataQuality
    from awsglue import DynamicFrame
    import gs_now
    
    def sparkSqlQuery(glueContext, query, mapping, transformation_ctx) -> DynamicFrame:
        for alias, frame in mapping.items():
            frame.toDF().createOrReplaceTempView(alias)
        result = spark.sql(query)
        return DynamicFrame.fromDF(result, glueContext, transformation_ctx)
    
    args = getResolvedOptions(sys.argv, ['JOB_NAME'])
    sc = SparkContext()
    glueContext = GlueContext(sc)
    spark = glueContext.spark_session
    job = Job(glueContext)
    job.init(args['JOB_NAME'], args)
    
    # Default ruleset used by all target nodes with data quality enabled
    DEFAULT_DATA_QUALITY_RULESET = """
        Rules = [
            ColumnCount >= max(last(1)),
            RowCount > avg(last(10))*0.6
        ]
    """
    
    t_df = glueContext.create_dynamic_frame.from_options(
        connection_type = "oracle",
        connection_options = {
            "useConnectionProperties": "true",
            "dbtable": "mywarehouse_t",
            "connectionName": "warehouse",
            "hashfield":"id"
  
        },
        transformation_ctx = "t_node",
        additional_options = {"JobBookmarkKeys": ["id", "key2"], 
                               "jobBookmarkKeysSortOrder": "asc"
                             }   
    )
    
    
    m_df = glueContext.create_dynamic_frame.from_options(
        connection_type = "oracle",
        connection_options = {
            "useConnectionProperties": "true",
            "dbtable": "mywarehouse_m",
            "connectionName": "base2",
            "hashfield":"key2"
            
           
        },
        transformation_ctx = "m_node"
    )
    
    # Script generated for node SQL Query
    sqlQuery = '''
    select t.*, m.tag from mywarehouse_t t
    inner join mywarehouse_m m on t.key2 = m.key2
    '''
    
    sql_node = sparkSqlQuery(glueContext, query = sqlQuery, mapping = {"mywarehouse_m":m_df , "mywarehouse_t":t_df}, 
    transformation_ctx = "sql_ctx")
    
    
    s3_node = glueContext.write_dynamic_frame.from_options(frame=sql_node, connection_type="s3", format="glueparquet", 
        connection_options={"path": "s3://my_s3", "partitionKeys": []}, 
        format_options={"compression": "snappy"}, 
        transformation_ctx="s3_node")
    
    
    job.commit()

